# Query Callback Not Called When Mongoose Connection Created In Another Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

When I query right after creating and opening mongoose connection as shown below, the query callback is hit and docs are loaded.

```javascript
var db,
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

...

MyClass.prototype.query = function(model, criteria, callback) {
  var options = {
    server: {
      auto_reconnect: true,
      socketOptions : {
        keepAlive: 1
      }
    }
  };

  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase', options);

  db = mongoose.connection;

  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error:'));

  db.once('open', function () {
    model.find(criteria).exec(function(err, docs) {
      callback(err, {}, docs);
    });
  });
};
```

However, when I create the connection in an `initDB` function and make the query later on as shown below, the callback is not called.  `initDB` is being called before `express` server is started.

```javascript
var db,
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

...

function initDB() {
  var options = {
    server: {
      auto_reconnect: true,
      socketOptions : {
        keepAlive: 1
      }
    }
  };

  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase', options);

  db = mongoose.connection;

  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error:'));
}

...

MyClass.prototype.query = function(model, criteria, callback) {
  db.once('open', function () {
    model.find(criteria).exec(function(err, docs) {
      callback(err, {}, docs);
    });
  });
};
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably because the callback passed to `db.once('open', ...` is being called only once when a connection to your database has been established.  Try moving the call to `db.once()` into your `initDB()` function as follows:

```javascript
var db,
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

...

function initDB() {
  var options = {
    server: {
      auto_reconnect: true,
      socketOptions : {
        keepAlive: 1
      }
    }
  };

  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase', options);

  db = mongoose.connection;

  db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected to database!');
  });

  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error:'));
}

...

MyClass.prototype.query = function(model, criteria, callback) {
  model.find(criteria).exec(function(err, docs) {
    callback(err, {}, docs);
  });
};
```